# unable to load owl file to android project using owl api

Tags: android, owl, owl-api

I have been trying to load an OWL file that I made in Protégé. I import OWL API 3.4.3 to my project and also passed the `sample.owl` file to raw folder, but when I try to load the OWL file, it doesn't work.  There was no error but I am just getting this message

> unfortunately, sampleproject has stopped

Here is the section of code am using. When I try the code in a standard Java environment it works without a problem.

```java
OWLOntology localOntology = null;
int rID = resources.getIdentifier("com.example.cammclient1:raw/"+"sample", null, null);
InputStream input = resources.openRawResource(rID);
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(input);

try {
  for (OWLClass cls : localOntology.getClassesInSignature()) {
    Log.d("class in the ontology", ((CharSequence) cls).toString());
  }
  TV1.setText("reading classes...............");
} 
catch (Exception e) {
  TV1.setText("Not successfull");
}
```

Comment: You're not getting stack traces because you're swallowing the exception in the try/catch block. You can either print the stack trace for e or set the text on TV1 to e.getMessage().

Comment: tnx for your replay, i have tried your suggestion too, but still it's not working... it crashes before the app starts...

Comment: Hard to suggest anything else. Try using 3.4.10

Comment: @Ignazio is there any tutorial or some example that i could get in how to utilize owl ontology in android

Comment: Not one specific for Android. There is one for general use at https:github.com/owlcs/owlapi linked in the wiki. Once I have some more experience on Android development I'll put a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `OWLClass` instances to `CharSequence` and then calling `toString()` on it.
This will cause `ClassCastException` to be thrown - an OWLClass is not a string.
Just use `cls.toString()` instead, you will have the same result.

You are also swallowing the exception in the catch block. That's not helpful in diagnosing the issue, as it hides information by just saying "Not successful" without providing more information.